# How to run flutter_web and angulardart on one machine with multiple Dart and webdev versions?

Tags: flutter, angular-dart, flutter-web

How to run flutter_web and angulardart on one machine with multiple Dart and webdev versions? Even if I set a different PATH when I need to switch Dart versions, two Dart versions are still using the same `webdev` which is not really correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(There is no official solution for this so far. Maybe the official team will provide one in the future.)*

The following is my solution. I am running MacOS. It should be the same in Linux and similar in Windows.

There are two things need to be taken care. (1) Dart SDK version (2) A different `PUB_CACHE` because `webdev` versions will be different.

I download the dart version required by angulardart manually from [this link](https://dart.dev/tools/sdk/archive) and put it somewhere **NOT** in the `PATH`. And put the dart for flutter and flutter_web in the `PATH`. (I will not explain this in detail. It should be pretty straightforward.)

Then I write three scripts and one env setup file:

- File `angular-env`:

```sh
export PUB_CACHE="$HOME/.pub-cache-angular"
export PATH="Override PATH"
```

**Note:** when you override PATH, make sure (1) Remove flutter dart bin, (2) Remove ${HOME}/.pub-cache/bin (3) add angulardart dart bin, (4) add $HOME/.pub-cache-angular/bin

- File `angular-dart`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

source angular-env

dart "$@"
```

- File `angular-pub`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

source angular-env

pub "$@"
```

- File `angular-webdev`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

source angular-env

webdev "$@"
```

Don't forget to make them executable.

Now, you can simply use `angular-pub global activate webdev` to install `webdev` for angulardart.

After this, everything should work. You can run `angular-webdev serve` in the angulardart project.

Check some of my terminal outputs:

```
$ dart --version
Dart VM version: 2.5.0-dev.1.0.flutter-fedd74669a (Sat Jul 20 00:05:23 2019 +0000) on "macos_x64"
$ angular-dart --version
Dart VM version: 2.2.1-dev.3.0 (Tue Apr 2 13:55:04 2019 +0200) on "macos_x64"
$ pub version
Pub 2.5.0-dev.1.0.flutter-fedd74669a
$ angular-pub version
Pub 2.2.1-dev.3.0
$ webdev --version
2.3.0
$ angular-webdev --version
2.0.5
```